# Set permissions for all files and folders recursively (Zend Framework 2)

Tags: php, zend-framework2, file-permissions

I want to set permissions for all files and folders recursively in ZF2.

My directory path is `/var/blabla/blabla/blabla/public/files/filename`

I want to set 0777 permisson for the main folder. I.e. foldername and all the contents of the folder.

I am using

```
public function chmod_r($dir, $dirPermissions, $filePermissions) {
    $dp = opendir($dir);
    while($file = readdir($dp)) {
        if (($file == ".") || ($file == ".."))
            continue;

        $fullPath = $dir."/".$file;

        if(is_dir($fullPath)) {
            echo('DIR:' . $fullPath . "\n");
            chmod($fullPath, $dirPermissions);
            chmod_r($fullPath, $dirPermissions, $filePermissions);
        } else {
            echo('FILE:' . $fullPath . "\n");
            chmod($fullPath, $filePermissions);
        }

    }
    closedir($dp);
}
```

as the function and calling it from my action as:

```
  $this->chmod_r($dirPath, 0777, 0777);
```

while $dirPath contains the path of the folder.

Comment: Remember that you need write permissions on this files and directories, else you cannot modify it. If you execute it with apache user then the apache user need this permissions

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($pathname), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($iterator as $item) {
    chmod($item, $filemode);
}
```

Hope this helps you in solving your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dirPath), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($iterator as $item) { 
    chmod($item, 0777);
}
```

I have done it in this way.. is it working for you?